# How can I correctly obtain the list of GrantedAuthority associated to an user using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am pretty new in Spring Security and I have the following problem trying to retrieve the **list of the **GrantedAuthority** related to a specific user.

So I have this method that retrive me the connected user (this works fine):

```
protected CustomUserDetail getUtenteConnesso() {
    return (CustomUserDetail) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

Then I am trying to do:

```
ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> autorizzazioni = (ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>) getUtenteConnesso().getAuthorities();
```

to retrieve the **GrantedAuthority** list associated to this user but when I perform this method an exception is thrown.

I think that the problem is that the signature of the **getAuthorities() method define into the **org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User** class is:

```
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}
```

So the method return a generic **Collection** interface.

I tryed to cast this **Collection** to into an **ArrayList** but seems can't work.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It isn't a list it is a collection. If you want an array list create a new one and add all authorities to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The interface returns a collection, so you cannot cast with ArrayList. You must use Collection:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
```

And if you want an arrayList, for instance :

```
List<GrantedAuthority> listAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
listAuthorities.addAll(authorities);
```

If you are interested in the internal behaviour of Spring, I detail below.
The interface specifies collection (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.java line 68):

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
```

Default abstract implementation uses ArrayList internally, but returns a Collection anyway (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationToken.java lines 67-70):

```
    private final Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    ...
    ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> temp = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(
            authorities.size());
    temp.addAll(authorities);
    this.authorities = Collections.unmodifiableList(temp);
```

The reason why is detailed in the Authentication interface javadoc : "Implementations should ensure that modifications to the returned collection array do not affect the state of the Authentication object, or use an unmodifiable instance."

That is why you cannot cast. A commentary suggested to create a new ArrayList and add all Authorities in it, if you really want a List.

Comment: Tnx so much, only a last doubt: why you first create the temp array with the specified number of the autorites and then add all these authorites to this array? Is for some security reason? Why? What can happen if I simply create a new array from the Collection of authorities?

Comment: That's not my code, that Spring Security 's. I just wanted to show the way it works, if you were interested to know that. The two first lines of my post : that is what you should do. You don't need to have a temp arraylst. I don't know why you need arrayList, but you can simply create a new arraylist with the Collection of Authorities, just like you suggest

Comment: I edited the post after your comment. I wanted to show you that, even if you've got a collection, this collection might be ordered because Spring manages ArrayList internally (well, by default at least). In any case, it was ordered when I used it. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: @AndreaNobili setting the initial size of `ArrayList` in constructor is a good practice whenever you know the required list size upfront because it lets you eliminate the need for extending the internal ArrayList storage, which is not free, and you use the optimal amount of memory.